# Unityで面白法人カヤックさんのLobiを使用するとBGMが割れる

Tags: ios, unity3d

Unityで作成したゲームにランキングを導入しようと、面白法人カヤックさんが公開しているLobiを導入してみたのですが、iOSにコンパイルした場合のみBGMが割れたような音?すごくピッチが遅くなったような音になりました。

現在導入しているプラグインをひとつずつ追加していき、確認したのでLobi導入による問題だとは特定したのですが、導入の仕方に問題があって起こった症状なのか、Lobiのバグなのかどちらかわからない状況です。

新しいプロジェクト作ってただBGM流してるだけの最小構成のアプリでもなったので、 
Lobiのバグだと思いたいんですが。。。 
これ以上どうしたらいいかわからなかったので、質問させていただきました。

Comment: LobiSDKのWikiを見ると、SampleRateに44100を指定する必要があると書かれています。ひょっとしてこれでしょうか？ https://github.com/kayac/Lobi/wiki/LobiSDK-Unity5

Comment: 申し訳ないんですが、これでした。
しっかり仕様を見ていないことを痛感しました。
本当にありがとうございました。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

改めて回答として投稿しておきます。

Github上のLobiSDKのWikiに、各環境ごとの導入手順書が載っています。で、[iOS+Unity](https://github.com/kayac/Lobi/wiki/iOS-Implement-LobiRecSDK-Unity)の手順の中に、「Unity 5での導入に関しては～」という記述があり、その[リンク先](https://github.com/kayac/Lobi/wiki/LobiSDK-Unity5)にこのように書かれています。

> ### Unityプロジェクトの設定
>
> - （省略）
> - `[Edit]-[Project Settings]-[Audio]` の `[Sample Rate]` に `44100` を設定して下さい（※お手数ですが、Android向けにビルドするときは、設定を空欄に戻してください）

サンプリングレートの設定が原因でピッチや再生速度がおかしくなるというのは、iOSやUnityに限らず、PC上での音楽制作などでも耳にする話ですね。